# WinRT OnSuspending

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

What does event OnSuspending in App.xaml.cs mean? I suppose this event is fired when we change Metro to Desktop or change metro application but what is done with app memory? Is it freed, saved somewhere or it is kept until OS exhausted memory? What steps I have to do as a programmer to keep application working after resuming? What do I need to save?

Comment: I'd start [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh464925.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your applications point of view, the suspend is somewhat like the 'pause' option of the debugger. Execution is completely stopped and the OS has the option to either resume the app at a later point or shut it down for good.

In the first scenario, your app will not have a clue about the meantime. In case it is shut down by the OS, on the next start the [previous execution state](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.activation.applicationexecutionstate.aspx) will be set to 'terminated' so you should restore the app as it was when you received the 'suspend' event.